# Page losing CSS Style after updating master page Controls

Tags: asp.net

ASP.3.5 No AJAX

Master page has a external style sheet. It has 2 dropdownlists in top section.

When a new item is inserted, a value is added to each of the dropdownlists. The newly added value has to be selected in the dropdownlists.

From my content page I update the dropdownlists on the master page. The dropdownlists are getting updated correctly, but I am losing the CSS styles.

Here's my Masterpage.aspx code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>My Project</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
```

Here' my content page code:

```
protected void formview_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception == null)
    {
        //Force the dropdownlistboxes in the master page also selects the newly inserted First
        DropDownList ddlFirst = Master.FindControl("ddlFirst") as DropDownList;
        if (ddlFirst != null)
        {
            ddlFirst.DataBind();
            Response.Write(ddlFirst.SelectedValue = Session["sFirstID"].ToString());
        }
        DropDownList ddlSecond = Master.FindControl("ddlSecond") as DropDownList;
        if (ddlSecond != null)
        {
            ddlSecond.DataBind();
            Response.Write(ddlSecond.SelectedValue = Session["sSecondID"].ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try:  `<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ></link>` p.s. why do you `Response.Write`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />
```